# Can GStreamer time-shift on a live feed?

Tags: video, gstreamer

A lot of livestreaming platforms allow you to time-shift within the stream while it's still ongoing.  For example, if you join 15 min late, you can watch it from the beginning on a 15 min delay or if you miss something, you can go back 30 seconds and see it again.  I'm wondering if something like this is possible with GStreamer.

What I'm really looking to accomplish is to have a live video feed on a slight (about 15 seconds) delay, but then also have the ability to go back and look at a section again, pause, or step through it frame-by-frame.  Once the analysis is done, I want to return to the (delayed) live feed.

I currently have it displaying the live feed with the delay by just putting a delay in the pipeline, but I'm obviously going to have to store it somewhere if I want to be able to dynamically shift within the stream.

My original thought was to have 2 threads, one which take the live feed and write it to a file and then second would play that file as it's being written, moving back and forth in it as necessary.  However, I've been unable to get GStreamer to play the file while it's being written, much less seek within it.

Since I only would need to go back at most 15 min, another option I've considered is a something like a rolling memory buffer instead of a file, but I'm not finding a lot of options there.

I am a bit of a GStreamer novice, so any suggestions are appreciated!